# @Nullable Ignored by guice

Tags: java, guice

I have a constructor like

```
@Inject
public FxManagerFactory(DataServicesClientAPI dsApi,
                        OptimisationHorizon horizon,
                        Logger logger,
                        ModelScenario modelScenario,
                        @Nullable LimDataProvider limDataProvider ){...}
```

and I am getting this error

```
null returned by binding at com.eet.mpm.portopt.domainmodel.modelrunners.PomModule.bindFactories(PomModule.java:171)
 but parameter 4 of com.eet.mpm.portopt.domainmodel.marketdata.FxManagerFactory.<init>() is not @Nullable
  while locating com.eet.mpm.pricecurves.LimDataProvider
    for parameter 4 at com.eet.mpm.portopt.domainmodel.marketdata.FxManagerFactory.<init>(FxManagerFactory.java:30)
  while locating com.eet.mpm.portopt.domainmodel.marketdata.FxManagerFactory
  at com.eet.mpm.portopt.domainmodel.modelrunners.PomModule.bindFactories(PomModule.java:172)
  while locating com.eet.mpm.portopt.intf.domainmodel.marketdata.IFxManager
```

at the second bind shown here

```
private void bindFactories() {
    bind(LimDataProvider.class).toProvider(LimDataProviderFactory.class).asEagerSingleton();
    bind(IFxManager.class).toProvider(FxManagerFactory.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

It runs locally ('works on my pc') and when I debug it but when executed in a different environment the error occurs.

I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226310/guice-ignoring-nullable-on-injected-constructor-parameter) but it seems related to eclipse which I don't think is relevant to this problem as I am not using eclipse.

Comment: Which @Nullable annotation are you using? Is does it have RUNTIME retention?

Comment: `@java.lang.annotation.Documented
@javax.annotation.Nonnull(when = javax.annotation.meta.When.UNKNOWN)
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@javax.annotation.meta.TypeQualifierNickname
public @interface Nullable {
}`

Comment: This appeared to be a dependency issue. 

The @Ignore attribute is defined in com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9

com.google.guava:11.0.1 depends on this.

However I had a module called say 'Fred' that depended on com.google.guava:11.0.1 and another module that depended on 'Fred' and additionally com.google.guava:11.0.1 say 'Bill'

Bill had the code shown in the question that was throwing. When I removed the additional dependency on com.google.guava:11.0.1 from Bill it worked again. Not sure why mind you.

Comment: Android comes with android.support.annotation.@Nullable which doesn't work with Guice AssistedInject. I use a jsr jar that has an @Nullable that does work. Jetbrains also works.