# @Nullable doesn't seem to work with @AssistedInject

Tags: java, guice, nullable, assisted-inject

I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
@Inject
public MyClass(
        @Named("config") String configFile,
        @Named("template") String templateFile,
        CachedSettings settings,
        @Assisted String channelId,
        @Nullable @Assisted("NetworkA") NetworkInterface localNetworkInterfaceA,
        @Nullable @Assisted("NetworkB") NetworkInterface localNetworkInterfaceB) {
```

And I get the following error (twice, once for each parameter)

```
1) null returned by binding at my.company.package.MyClassFactory.create()
 but parameter 4 of my.company.package.MyClass.<init>() is not @Nullable
  while locating java.net.NetworkInterface annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=NetworkA)
   for parameter 4 at my.company.package.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:24)
  while locating my.company.package.MyClass annotated with interface com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted
```

Any idea what is wrong? I found two other questions on this issue, one of them said it was a [dependency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483650/nullable-ignored-by-guice) which I don't think I have, the other said it was an [Eclipse issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226310/guice-ignoring-nullable-on-injected-constructor-parameter), which I do use, but I refreshed, cleaned, and rebuilt my maven projects from scratch, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I am using [javax.annotation.Nullable](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/Nullable.html), which is supposed to be retained at Runtime. What else should I try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Nullable` needs to be set on both the constructor as well as the factory declaration. We use `FactoryModuleBuilder` to declare our Factories. I am pasting the relevant bits of code that work for us

### The constructor:

```
@Inject
public AddressActions(EC2Service ec2Service,
                      RequestFactory requestFactory,
                      @Assisted("spiceManager") SpiceManager spiceManager,
                      @Assisted("parent") Context parent,
                      @Assisted("publicIp") @Nullable String publicIp) {
```

### The Abstract Factory:

```
public static interface Factory {
    AddressActions create(@Assisted("spiceManager") SpiceManager spiceManager,
                          @Assisted("parent") Context context,
                          @Assisted("publicIp") @Nullable String publicIp);
}
```

### The Factory Module Builder:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(AddressActions.Factory.class));
```

### The call:

```
AddressActions actions = actionsFactory.create(spiceManager, getSherlockActivity(), null);
```

Relevant versions:

- Guice: `guice-3.0-no_aop.jar`
- AssistedInject: `guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar`
- JSR305: `jsr305-1.3.9.jar`

-k